# typedef uint32 conflict in C

Tags: c

including two external header files int my .c file results in a typedef conflict of unit32 since that type is defined differently in both files (`typedef unsigned long` in the first one and `typedef unsigned int` in the second one). The code is for a 32bit microcontroller.
Whats the best way to resolve such a problem without changing the code in the external files? I did a lot of research with google but I couldn't find a solution. I found the following thread: [C typedef name conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291228/c-typedef-name-conflict).
I tried that way but it didn't work. Sinsce I neither understand how that solution works it is easyli possible that i did a mistake in my code. Could somebody give me an example how to implement it?
Thanks

Comment: Please include some code.

Comment: It would be helpful to have a look at the headers, if they are publicly accessible.

Comment: I'd be suspicious of code that typedefs `unsigned long uint32_t`. That could be intended for 16-bit platforms.

Comment: @EOF 32bit platforms commonly have `int` and `long` both 32bits (ILP32).

Comment: @EOF: `unsigned long` is 32 bits for most 32 bit platforms, too. You might be thinking about 64 bit platforms where it is often 64 bits (e.g. Linux-x64).

Comment: @Quentin: Sure, on most 32-bit platforms you *could* typedef it that way... but why would you?

Comment: I would use the standard header `stdint.h`. Using custom types for fixed size integers has become an obsolete legacy with C99. Do not use this anymore. If that is not possible, you might `#define uint32 uint32_t` in your code.

Comment: Include `stdint.h`  and use the `typedef` from there.  Pitch the others.  I'd post this as an answer if I knew your platform had `stdint.h`.

Comment: @EOF: To use the same file for 16 and 32 bit platforms? (not how I would do it, but ... I would not use custom types here either).

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I strongly disagree! OP should `#include <stdint.h>` and not just copy the definition to his own headers.

Comment: @Olaf: That's my point, it's probably code that's got some 16-bit history/legacy.

Comment: @Olaf - You misunderstand my meaning - the implied part being to `#include <stdint.h>`.  (Comment has been edited to make that clear)

Comment: @EOF: Got it. Problem is you will find tons of code of this kind, as with ARM Cortex-M a lot of old software is ported. So reason to be suspicious **per se**. But as of not using `stdint.h`. That should be changed for a port - along with many other legacy crap. (I'm actually strongly advocating not only to port, but to re-implement such code, as custom fixed-size types are often just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I assume that was directed to me. Sorry I missunderstood. So we both agree to agree.

Comment: @Olaf - Yep.  I fixed the tag.

Comment: "it didn't work". This gives zero useful information. Since it's a working solution, try harder, or at least try to convey where and how exactly it fails.

Answer (score 1):

Since both definitions depict a 32-bit `unsigned int` (e.g. by calling it `uint32`), it's *supposed* to represent 4-byte `unsigned int`, whichever way it is defined.  You should check `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(long)` in your specific compiler.

For a 32-bit hobbyist microcontroller, probably the following is true:

`sizeof(long) == sizeof(int)`

Assuming both `typedefs` are defining an unsigned 4-byte `int`, there is no practical difference in usage.

If they are *different* sizes, then one of the typedefs is erroneously named `uint32`, and should be named `uint16`, or `uint64` depending on the size for that type in the compiler.

However, if you change the `typedef` name to make it more accurate, you have to find any other code that uses the typedef and have it use the right typedef based on the storage size required.

Since it's a compiler for a microcontroller, there probably isn't a software stack above yours that includes either file, so you're probably OK. E.g. only code you wrote matters, but check, in case there is other software that includes code, and update accordingly.

In case some code would include one header but not the other, you need to ensure it gets defined in whichever `.h` is included, but to also ensure the `uint32` type is only defined once, you can add a 'guard' using the C pre-compiler to protect against multiple inclusions (and ensuing compile time   conflict errors) as follows:

In one .h file:

```
#ifndef _UINT32
typedef unsigned long uint32
#define _UINT32
#endif
```

In the other:

```
#ifndef _UINT32
typedef unsigned int uint32
#define _UINT32
#endif
```

Comment: finished my edits. Sorry, my answer evolved a lot after first post.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, isn't there a fine solution without changing the code of the external header files?

Comment: Pls. thank w/up vote on answer. To answer your question: Ask yourself, is it a vendor bug? Should you report it? (yes). They might fix it in a patch or update. `uint32/uint32_t` should be defined in `types.h` or similar to avoid that kind of prob. Who are the other consumers? Does it make more sense to fix it where the problem is, once and for all? Could your fix be ruined by subsequent vendor update? It's not UNIX, where there are a lot of consumers & requires root access. It's intimate; affects only you. Your compiler. Obvious fix. I would fix it at the source - problem solved.

Comment: The reason there aren't great solutions for the problem is that it is a basic design bug that is easily avoidable and should have been avoided by the providers and architects of the header files. That's why all those types should have been defined in one header file with inclusion guards (to prevent re-inclusion no matter how many header files include it). Then it would be a non issue. That is the real solution, not hacky after-the-fact fixes. Just proper header design.  That's why I think you or vendor should fix it. What I recommended is an easy, reliable, safe & sane workaround.